# PHP Count Showing 2 Elements in Array, For Loop Loops 4 Times

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I want to loop through. Using:

```
echo count($places);
```

I get a value of 2. Similar `print_r` the array gives `2` items.

However, when i run a for loop it seems to go through 4 iterations. This can be seen by adding `echo $i` to the loop, which produces an output of 0,1,2,3.

This is my code:

```
function enrichfromDB($places) {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db1");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo count($places);
print_r($places);
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($places) ; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    $name = $places[$i]['name'];
    $gettag = "SELECT Tag FROM PlaceTags WHERE Name = '$name'";
    $data = mysqli_query($con,$gettag);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        $tags[] = $row['Tag'];
    }
    $places[$i]['category_labels'][0][] = $tags[$i];
}
return $places;
}
```

Comment: print your `places` array.

Comment: Your code is vunerable to SQL injection. Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix this. Use prepared statements and bind variables or at *least* escape your variables.

Comment: is `$places` keyed by anything else than (0,1) ? If yes, you would add more entries with the last line of the loop. Try `foreach ($places as $i=>$place)` and replace references to `$places[$i]` with `$place` inside the loop.

Comment: `var_dump` `$places` at the beginning of your function and note the keys. I bet they are not 0 and 1. Start using `foreach` and rid yourself of such cases.

Comment: Man this function is extremely spaghetti , advice rewrite the whole thing, too many things can go wrong and still not returning errors and function will continue running; I would take the SQL out of there first; then add a die() in case mysql con failed then I would expect the array problem to be fixed

Comment: Mysql edit also, u don't need all those select statements ! U can do ( Select tag from placestag where name in (". Implode(' ,', array_values($places)) . ");" !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count($places)
```

has a value of 2.

However, with the row of

```
$places[$i]['category_labels'][0][] = $tags[$i];
```

you are creating new elements inside your places array. Initially you had two elements, but some of the indexes you are using are not existent in the array, so they are created. Take a closer look at your array to solve your problem.